# Coredata predicate for matching strings in columns with multiple words in any order of occurrence

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I want to write a `CoreData` Predicate to check how many records from a column matches with any of the keywords entered irrespective of order in which they appear.

Ex. Suppose I have a record with "This is my test string to compare", now if I search with "test my compare" it should return this record.

I have tried using separating the words and using `CONTAINS` for each word and `OR`ed , but it is taking forever for result to come as there are more than 15000 records in db.

Please help.

Comment: Predicate with CONTAINS ?

Comment: What predicate are you currently using?  Is the problem getting the correct syntax, of getting the fetch to run efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Create contains `predicate` for each word in the string and Use `NSCompoundPredicate` of AND type.

```
 let string = "test my compare"
     var pridicateArray : [NSPredicate]!
     for word in string.components(separatedBy: " ") {
            let newPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "YOUR_ENTITY contains[c] %@", word)
            pridicateArray.append(newPredicate)
     }
   let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.and, subpredicates: pridicateArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// MARK: Step:1 this function will return predicate   

func getPredicate(searchStr: String) -> NSPredicate {
        var searchPredicate = NSPredicate()
        var pridicateArray = [NSPredicate]()
            if searchStr.contains(find: " ") {
                for searchWord in searchStr.components(separatedBy: " ") {
                    let newPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.searchable contains[c] %@", searchWord)
                    pridicateArray.append(newPredicate)
                }
                searchPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.and, subpredicates: pridicateArray)
            } else {
                searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.searchable contains[c] %@", searchStr)
            }

        return searchPredicate
    }

// MARK: Step:2 assign predicate to core data fetch request like below

fetchRequest.predicate = self.getPredicate(searchStr: "multi word string")
```